# Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without android:exported property set

Tags: android

I am trying to upload app to play store but getting this error:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

My Manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.aishcrypt.transfer"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <!-- remove permissions that your app doesn't require;
    asking for authority over unwanted information can cause damage to your reputation among your users -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- remove location.gps feature if not using permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

    <!--<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,UnusedAttribute">
        <activity
            android:name="com.aishcrypt.transfer.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.aishcrypt.transfer.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >      <!-- remove or alter as your apps requirement -->
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="apps.mgks.dev"
                    android:pathPrefix="/swv" />
                <!-- if you want only a specific directory from your website to be opened in the app through external links -->
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="OpenURI">
                <action android:name="Open_URI" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.aishcrypt.transfer.ShareActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="Share">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <!-- <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--<receiver android:name=".NotificationPausePlay" />-->
        <service android:name="com.aishcrypt.transfer.Firebase">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The error message and link give very clear advice, have you tried to follow its recommendations?

Comment: @PPartisan  i followed the recommendation but did notfind myself on good to do it as trying to do another error or same